# Spark running time in local changes a lot with "println"

Tags: scala, matrix, apache-spark, time

A tricky problem happened related to the sharp increase of executing time.

I run my scala code in local spark, part of which is to build a `n*n` matrix.

When running a small dataset, it just takes **5s** to finish. The most time-consuming part is to build `2000*2000` matrix. And this part is executed within `map`, which just deals with `array` data structure.

**However**, just out of curiosity, I add "println" within the matrix-building code to see the number of iterations. Suddenly, the whole running time increases to **1min23s**.

And the final results are same.

I am new to Spark and have no idea what really causes this situation.

The codes are simply:

```
val x = someRDD.map(buildMatrix)

def buildMatrix(stringVect:Array[String]): Array[Array[Double]] = {
      //var count = 0
      val num = stringVect.length
      var simi_matrix = Array[Array[Double]]()
      for (i<- 0 until num-1){
          for (j<- (i+1) until num){
             "build the matrix with some computation"
             //println(count)
             //count += 1
          }
      }
}
```

Comment: println simply takes some time, too. You are trying to print approximately 2 million lines to the console. 1 min 23 secs seems quite normal to me

Comment: @FrankLauterwald Thanks. It just surprised me that the time increased 16 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR

This does not have to do anything with Spark. I/O access to the console is synchronized and costly. It will slow down any program on the JVM (Scala/Java/Clojure/...).

---

`println` [defaults to `java.lang.System.out`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/Console.scala#L138) which is a `PrintStream`. `println` delegates to `PrintStream#println`, hence entering  the [synchronized block of the `println`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/PrintStream.java#PrintStream.println%28java.lang.String%29) implementation to output to the console: There are two expenses:

- Getting a synchronized lock
- I/O to the console OutputStream

The slowdown observed is to be expected. Just don't use `println` in hot parts of the code (like a tight loop in this case).